# RAILS Active record search with multiple ordering -- out of order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to display reports that meet criteria and display them in a particular order.

Sort by user, then by report creation date of the report, newest on top

```
@report_results.order('created_at DESC, user_id')
```

Above is the code I use, however, when the data is displayed, toward the end of each user's reports, they start to show up out of order.

How do I Fix this?

View:

```
 <% @report_results.order('created_at DESC, user_id').each do |report| %>
```

[image: Screenshot of results]

Comment: Are the ids listed here the report_result ids or the user_ids?

Comment: report IDs for 1 user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% @report_results.order('user_id').order('created_at DESC').each do |report| %>
```

Not sure why this works, I thought the last order command would overwrite the previous, but it seems like it retains it.

Items now show up grouped by user_id, in descending chronological order.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
variable = report_results.order('created_at DESC')

@report_results = variable.group_by(&:user_id)
```

This should return a hash of user_id with the respective reports ordered.

Comment: If I do this, how would I change my existing loop in my view?
<% @report_results.order('created_at DESC, user_id').each do |report| %>

Comment: Please update your question with the code in your view